# Swift - Detect UICollectionView cell at specific CGPoint

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, uicollectionviewcell

I have implemented a UICollectionView cell which can be scrolled horizontally. While scrolling, is it possible to detect which cell(index) is passing the first cell(among all visible cells in UICollectionView)??

I don't know whether I cleared my question. You can see the following picture...[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13404661/4549304 You can visit this link, You can get the cgpoint, then convert it to cell on a particular collection view, get the cell from there..

Comment: Ops, I think that I got it wrong, my answer is not what are you looking for :( However, there is `visibleCells` UICollectionView method might be useful t your case.

Comment: Glad it worked.